# Moving files to end of path

Tags: bash, file, move

Would anyone know how to move a file to the very end of a file path? I have tried looking this up but haven’t gotten anywhere. What I’m trying to do is:

```
mv filename.txt dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
```

I don’t want to list out every directory. Any way to just send it all the way to the end? Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Move it using what? Command line? On linux? Your question is ambiguous. You need to explain in way more detail than that lol

Comment: My bad. In bash

Comment: Not a duplicate. I know how to move the file by type I g out the full path. I just don’t want to type out the full path every single time I need to move it. I’m just not sure if there is a shorter way to do it.

Comment: Then please update your question to explain so, as I said, you need every single detail in there, we can't guess what you have on your mind and what you want done, right? :)

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate as currently worded.  If you want to move a file into the `abcdefghijk` directory, you can't do that by typing `mv file x/` just because you don't want to type `abcdefghijk`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you just need a shell variable to save you from having to repeatedly type out a long path, thus:

```
p=dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
mv filename1.txt $p
mv filename2.txt $p
...
```

And if you need the $p variable to be always set, you can define it in your .bash_profile or .bashrc file.

Comment: Yeah I think this might be the correct answer. Other than creating an alias for the directory there's no other way of doing it.